# jquery show input based on select dropdown

Tags: jquery

Looking to show an input field if a certain select field is 'selected'. It works the initial time. However, if you click around the select inputs, it does not work the next time.

### JQuery

```
$('#select-users').on('change', function() {
  if(this.value == "individual-user")
  {
    $("#individual-user").removeAttr("hidden");
  } else
  {
   $("#individual-user").hide();
  }
});
```

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/29k6n2jb/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#select-users').on('change', function() {
    if(this.value == "individual-user")
    {
        $("#individual-user").show();
    } else
    {
       $("#individual-user").hide();
    }
});
```

counterpart of `.hide()` is `.show()`

refer to : **[jsfiddle](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

Because you remove an attribute called `hidden` - rather than remove the attribute, call `.show()`

http://jsfiddle.net/29k6n2jb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.show()`, not `.removeAttr("hidden");`

`hide()` uses the `display` attribute, not the `hidden` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you use `.removeAttr("hidden")`, you are removing the attribue `hidden` from your html element, but if it does not match you are calling `.hide()` which adds the style attribute `dispplay:none` to your html element.

Instead you need to use `.show()` and `.hide()`

**css:**

```
#individual-user{
    display:none;
}
```

**html:**

```
<input type="text" id="individual-user" name="individual-user" class="form-control" value="User ID"/>
```

**js:**

```
$('#select-users').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == "individual-user") {
        $("#individual-user").show();
    } else {
        $("#individual-user").hide();
    }
});
```